# jQuery. How to uncheck all checkboxes except one (which was checked)

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have html items, 4 example:

```
<div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" class="foo"> Checkbox</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" class="foo"> Checkbox</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" class="foo"> Checkbox</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" class="foo"> Checkbox</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" class="foo"> Checkbox</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" class="foo"> Checkbox</div>
</div>
```

And now, I want next: If I click on any checkbox - the checkbox should be checked and other checkboxes should be unchecked. How can I do it?

Comment: What you want is called a radio button...

Comment: @François Wahl, no problem! I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use `radio` button and group them by name attributes. If you have to do it with `checkboxes` then you can do it this way,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/6D9kS/)**

```
$('.foo').click(function(){     
      $('.foo').attr('checked', false);
      $(this).attr('checked', true);          
});
```

For dynamically generated html you need [**on**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) that allows you to delegate the event with static parent, you can use document with you do not know static parent.

```
$(document).on('click','.foo', function(){     
      $('.foo').attr('checked', false);
      $(this).attr('checked', true);          
});
```

Document could be replaced by static parent if it is known. e.g. if div contain dynamically generated has id `parentdiv` then you can have

```
`$('#parentdiv').on('click','.foo', function(){`
```

**Edit**

**Use `prop` instead of `attr`** for properties `checked`, `selected`, or `disabled` as per documentation.

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as
>   the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the
>   .prop() method.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. I know about `radiobutton` group. But I cannot use it, because I must have different name params for my Spring MVC controller. By the reason, I've decided to use checkbox and JavaScript

Comment: +1: for working solution and DEMO. In general, a 1-liner alternative would be: `$('.foo').not(this).attr('checked', false);`

Comment: Thanks @FrançoisWahl, The suggested statement is very nice.

Comment: Guys, it doesn't work, if html has been generated dynamically by jQuey! :(  What should I do in the situation?

Comment: You need to on for binding click event, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl your's answer worked as a charm. Thanks

Comment: coming late to the party, but I miss one thing here: One of the few reasons why one would prefer a set of (exclusive) checkboxes over a radio group, is the fact that you could uncheck all of them, while with a radio group, once clicked, there is no way to revert to "none checked" state. Is there a jquery solution for that?

Answer (score 13):

Another solution

```
$('.foo').click(function(){     
      $('.foo').not(this).attr('checked', false);      
});
```

Comment: this answer is very underrated

Comment: If this doesn't work, try    `$('.foo').not(this).prop('checked', false);`

Answer (score 2):

jQuery V: 1.6 =<

```
$( ".foo" ).change(function() {
    $('.foo').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you:

```
.siblings("input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked", true);
```

will select all the checkboxes except for the one that was clicked.

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function() {

  if ($(this).val() == "none") {
    
    $(this).siblings("input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked', false);
    
  } else {
    
    $(this).siblings("input[value=none]").attr('checked', false);

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

  <input type="checkbox" id="worker-soft-eaglesoft" checked><label for="worker-soft-eaglesoft">&nbsp;Eaglesoft</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="worker-soft-dentrix"><label for="worker-soft-dentrix">&nbsp;Dentrix</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="worker-soft-softDent"><label for="worker-soft-softDent">&nbsp;Soft-Dent</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="worker-soft-denticon"><label for="worker-soft-denticon">&nbsp;Denticon</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="worker-soft-other"><label for="worker-soft-other">&nbsp;Other</label><br>

  <input type="checkbox" id="worker-soft-none" value="none">
  <label for="worker-soft-none">&nbsp;No Software Experience - Paper Records Only</label><br>
</div>
```