# How to remove checked="checked" for unchecked checkboxes with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

This is my current script

```
 <script>
        $().ready(function(){

                $('.prettycheckbox').click(function () {
                      $('.prettycheckbox input').removeAttr('checked');
                      $('.prettycheckbox a').removeClass('checked'); 

                      $("a", this).addClass('checked');
                      $("input", this).addAttr("checked");
                });

        });
 </script>
```

But it's not working well, bceause the part with adding and removing class to links works nice , but for input it doesn't work.

How to make the "checked" checkbox looks like this:

```
<input class="payment_type" type="checkbox" value="1" name="payment_type" style="display: none;" checked="checked">
```

and all others look like this?:

```
<input class="payment_type" type="checkbox" value="1" name="payment_type" style="display: none;">
```

How to do that? Something like input radio type using jquery and checkboxes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery. How to uncheck all checkboxes except one (which was checked)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739115/jquery-how-to-uncheck-all-checkboxes-except-one-which-was-checked)

Comment: The method is `.attr( "checked", "checked" )` but it's not what you want anyway, because the attribute `"checked"` refers to `.defaultChecked` property and you want to change `.checked`. Changing `.defaultChecked` property or `"checked"` attribute will only have effect if the user has not touched the checkbox yet.

Comment: For some reason this is working ;D `$('.prettycheckbox input').removeAttr('checked');
         $('.prettycheckbox a').removeClass('checked'); 
         
         
         
         $("a", this).addClass('checked');
         $("input", this).attr("checked", true);`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In,

### jQuery 1.6+

To change the property of checkbox you should use the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) function.

```
$('.prettycheckbox input').prop('checked', false);
$('.prettycheckbox input').prop('checked', true);
```

### jQuery 1.5 and below

The `.prop()` function doesn't exist, but [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) does similar:

```
$('.prettycheckbox input').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

*Note*: `removeAttr` is valid, but `addAttr` is not.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to change `checked` value

```
$('.prettycheckbox input').prop('checked', false);
```

Something else to remark, method `addAttr` doesn't exist

Comment: But doen't this depend on the jquery version, if OP is using older than 1.6, he/she may use .attr()

Comment: This is working: `$('.prettycheckbox input').removeAttr('checked');
         $('.prettycheckbox a').removeClass('checked'); 
         
         
         
         $("a", this).addClass('checked');
         $("input", this).attr("checked", true);` Can you explain why?

Comment: @michaelkonstincs: It's not clear what you're trying to do. It seems that you're trying to check and uncheck on the same method

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I thought that the code I provided in my question is clear. I mean click(), then remove, remove, add,add. Hmm, nevermind. it's probably only for advanced jquery users.

Comment: @michaelkonstincs: LOL yeah, your code is a master piece beyond my understanding skills.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
document.getElementById("check1").checked = true;
document.getElementById("check1").checked = false;
```