# Can I change Input tag radio checked value with time changes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making an auto slider with CSS, HTML, js I want to change checked value input type="radio" with time change...

```html
<div id="slide">
  <input type="radio" name="pos" id="pos1" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="pos" id="pos2">
  <input type="radio" name="pos" id="pos3">
  <input type="radio" name="pos" id="pos4">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <p class="pos">
    <label for="pos1"></label>
    <label for="pos2"></label>
    <label for="pos3"></label>
    <label for="pos4" checked></label>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need JavaScript or jQuery to do this. See here for somewhere to start: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18086342/8230810

Comment: Was the answer helpful?